# How to select current row in SAP GUI Grid View with VBA Macro?

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I am trying to automate a repetitive task in the SAP GUI. I need to search for an order number, select the row that the order number is in and then click a button to complete the task. I have recorded a macro which gives me:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarButton "&FIND"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtGS_SEARCH-VALUE").text = "4521305207"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtGS_SEARCH-VALUE").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = ""
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "2894"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[14]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[1,6]").selected = true
```

The line:

```
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtGS_SEARCH-VALUE").text = "4521305207"
```

Corresponds to the order I want to search, but if I change this value it still tries to process the same order that the macro was recorded on, I'm assuming because of the line:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "2894"
```

Does anyone know how I would go about finding the number of the row which corresponds to the outcome of the SEARCH-VALUE and then using that as the .selectedRows = ""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd really recommend you add a reference to the native SAP library. Go to your VBA Editor, click Tools, then References, then Browse, and find this file: "C:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapfewse.ocx". Add it, and now you'll have types and libraries and coding for SAP will be a lot easier, safer, and slightly faster (Variant types in VBA impose a tiny overhead that in this case is totally unnecessary). Get familiar with this new library if you are going to do any SAP scripting more than once.

Second, about this problem, what you have is a shell, of type `GuiShell`, which inherits from `GuiGridView`. `GuiGridView` looks like a table, a classic Excel-like set of rows and columns. In your transaction, is showing you a big list of orders, in which you go click the "Find" button, put the order you're looking for, and then close the Search Window. Back to your (Grid)Shell, this cell has been selected (Grid has properties `SelectedCells`, `SelectedRows`, `SelectedColumns` that get all set when you go find something), but then you go and modify the value of `SelectedRows` to a specific one.

So yeah, upon find, a cell has been selected, so all you need is to query its row and then assign it where you need:

```
Dim numrRow As Long
numrRow = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").CurrentCellRow
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").SelectedRows = numrRow
```

where "thisShell" is however you do to find a reference to the Shell (`session.findByID("blabla")` for example, but I'd advise to reduce all the findByID's, they're very slow and type-unsafe).

If you need help about this SAP libraries, feel free to maybe make some new post and ping me on the comments about it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I will be sure to take you up on your kind offer of help for future queries as our current SAP implementation leaves a lot to be desired and I will no doubt be back.

Comment: Hi, when I implement this for some reason it does not select the whole row, when I run the script the cursor highlights the block next to the row (where you would click if you were to select it manually) with a dotted square outline but its as if it does not then 'click' to select and highlight the actual row. The script then breaks at session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[14]").press

Comment: @Logan9Fingers, I just checked how I had it exactly in my codebase, pretty much as I said, I just cleaned it a bit now. I think that maybe you also want to select a cell in particular, not just the row. There are functions in GuiGridView called "SetCurrentCell" and "PressButton" that both take as a parameter the row number and the column name (.ColumnOrder would also tell you the column names by the way), you can explore those maybe. What error do you get exactly at that line by the way?

Comment: It works now. I don't know what I was doing wrong. Thanks for updating, much appreciated.

Comment: Please could you answer this question if you get chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130754/how-to-set-current-cell-on-sap-guicontainershell-in-c

Comment: Hello, I was using "....CurrentCellRow" to get the current row index of the grid; something like this., { session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabs........[1,session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabs....").CurrentCellRow]").text = "..Some Value.." }; but get the error - "Object Doesn't support this property or method".